# Proof involving Gauss–Seidel method.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I've got a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ that I decompose into $A=U+R$ where $U$ is the upper triangular portion of $A$ including the diagonal and $R$ is $A-U$. I've shown that $$x^TAx = (1+\lambda)x^TUx$$ with $x$ an eigen-vector of $U^{-1}R$ with eigen-value $\lambda$ and from the previous I know $\lambda \neq -1$. Now I'm supposed to prove $$x^TAx \leq 2x^TUx$$ to show that $|\lambda| < 1$ and the method converges. I'm having a bit of trouble showing this inequality holds $$x^TAx \leq 2x^TUx$$

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints.  Since $A$ is symmetric, we have $U = R^T + D$, where $R^T$ is the portion of $A$ above the diagonal, and $D$ is the diagonal part.  Since $A$ is positive definite, the diagonal entries of $D$ are positive.

Comment: Not quite sure how that helps. I can see $U = R^t + D$ that makes perfect sense I can see that the entries of $D$ have to be positive with no problem. But when I use that substitution I get $x^TAx = x^T(R^T + D + R)x = x^{T}R^{T}x + x^{T}Dx + x^{T}R x$ since $x^{T}R^{T}x \in \mathbb{R}$ (for what I'm looking at) does it follow that I can interchange $(x^{T}R^{T}x)^T = x^{T}R x$ so that I can combine terms and use the positive nature of $D$?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it.

Comment: Right then; Thank you for your assistance